# List of dataframes - extracting a row from each dataframe

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes who were created by importing excel files, which had not unique structure, e.g.:

sometimes I have a label `"Contact"` in cell `A8`, sometimes in `A9`. But it is always labeled as `"Contact"`.

I know how to extract `"Contact"` if Contact would be in a fixed position, e.g. `A9`. In that case I would write this code:

```
lapply(test,"[",9,1,drop=FALSE)
```

How should I change code to dynamically find in which row the label `"Contact"` appears in every dataframe?

Thanks!

I see I wasn't clear enough. Ok, here is the picture of 2 DF of many in my list. You can see the "Company name" value is in 8th row of the first DF and in 10th of the second DF. How can I dynamically get the row with this function lapply(test,"[",9,1,drop=FALSE)?

[Example of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYQ5y.png)

Comment: Couldn't you define the column that includes the word "Contact" (probably the first column) to be the row names of the dataframe? Then you can access the row by "test["Contact",]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you should use `which()` to find the row with your target string like so:

```
df <- data.frame(cont = c(rep("Some data",7),"Contact",rep("Some data",2)), val = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = F)
df[which(df$cont == "Contact"),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `test` is your dataframe, and the string `"Contact"` is in the first column and in unknown row. 
Then you could define the first column as the row names of the dataframe.

```
test <- data.frame(names=c("contact","other"), x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4))
rownames(test) <- test[,1]
```

and access the row in question by

```
test["contact",]
```